# Excel string extract

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, string-manipulation

I have a string in a cell:

```
ABCDxxxxxEFGH
```

`ABCD` and `EFGH` are constants, and `xxxxx` is of variable length.

How do I write an Excel formula to extract `xxxxx`?

Answer (score 13):

Assuming it is in Cell A1

```
=MID(A1,5,LEN(A1)-8)
```

If you wanted to check that the cell is correctly formed you could do:

```
=IF(LEN(A1)>8,IF(AND(LEFT(A1,4)="ABCD",RIGHT(A1,4)="EFGH"),MID(A1,5,LEN(A1)-8),NA()),NA())
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to brute force it (assuming ABCD and EFGH aren't within xxxxx then the following approach should work, although I would recommend you come up with a better method.

```
myvariable = split(split(cell, "ABCD")(1), "EFGH")(0)
```

(Please excuse if my syntax is slightly off. It's been a while since I've been in [VBScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VBScript).)